# What will happen to expired PubSub message in Dataflow streaming pipeline?

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub, apache-beam-io

Dataflow streaming job reads messages from PubSub and processes it somehow.
But sometimes, for example because of very long processing time, this message is not acked on time and PubSub redelivers this message.
We can see it in dataflow logs where two in fact the same messages (the same `message_id`) are processed at the same time.

My question is: what will happen to this "old" (first) PubSub message, that is still processed but in fact is expired because new deliver just arrived.
If this first message finishes finally the process before second (redelivered one) message, will it go further to next step or will be dropped (because is expired)?

Answer (score 1):

Dataflow messages will be acked after a message is successfully processed by first fused stage.
In cases where a message is seen twice, Dataflow will mark the latter message as Duplicate and filter it out provided you are using the built-in Apache Beam PubsubIO. This filtering is achieved based on the unique message_id provided by Pub/Sub.

More info can be found in https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/handling-duplicate-data-in-streaming-pipeline-using-pubsub-dataflow

Answer (score 1):

Based on this [document](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/handling-failures) If Pub/Sub attempts to deliver a message but the subscriber can't acknowledge it, Pub/Sub will retry sending the message.By default, Pub/Sub will try resending the message immediately. To address this issue, Pub/Sub lets you configure an [exponential backoff policy](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/handling-failures#exponential-backoff) for better flow control.
The idea behind exponential backoff is to add progressively longer delays between retry attempts. After the first delivery failure, Pub/Sub will wait for a minimum backoff time before retrying.

When Dataflow receives messages from Pub/Sub subscription, messages are acknowledged after they are successfully processed. If a message has not been acknowledged within its acknowledgement time period, Dataflow attempts to maintain the lease on the message by repeatedly extending the time period to prevent redelivery from Pub/Sub. However this is best effort and there is a possibility that messages may be redelivered.

Already mentioned by @codeNinja:

As Pub/Sub provides each message with a unique message_id, Dataflow uses it to deduplicate messages by default when you are using the built-in Apache Beam PubSubIO. Dataflow filters out such duplicates originating from redelivery of the same message by Pub/Sub.